# JasperReports empty chart at Report Group change

Tags: jasper-reports, grouping, ireport

I am using JasperReports with iReport to generate reports from a MySQL data source. The reports I am attempting to generate use Report Groups to organize the information. Also, I have a chart that appears at the footer of each page displaying info for the current grouping. The chart's reset type is Group, and it is placed in the column footer to achieve this. Also, a new page is forced when the report group changes.

The problem that I am having is that when the Report Group changes, (at the last page of each grouping) I am left with an empty chart on that page. On the proceeding pages, the chart resumes with valid data.

Does anyone have any tips as to how I can fix this?

- A good solution would have the chart displaying the data for the group.
- An okay solution would have the chart hidden at the time of a report grouping change

Answer (score 2):

In iReport Designer

1. Right Click On the Chart
2. Select Chart Data
3. Under Dataset tab, select 'Group' for 'Reset type'
4. Select the group for which you want to reset the chart for 'Reset group'

Comment: Your answer helped me in finding the solution to my problem in Jasper studio. +1 for this.